# DB trusted_connection not working

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub INTL()   
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection 
  Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset 
  Dim thisSql As String  
  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
  Dim sConn As String   sConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Server=mydb;trusted_connection=yes" conn.Open sConn      
  'Set and Excecute SQL Command'     
  thisSql = "select top 5 * from useraccount"               
  'Open Rcordset'     
  Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset        
  rec1.Open thisSql, conn       
  'Copy Data to Excel'         
  ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)  
End Sub
```

The code is not compiling in excel , error :Sub or function not defined

Comment: Which line is the compile error on? BTW your question title has nothing to do with your question it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in your IDE exactly like this:

```
Dim sConn As String   sConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Server=mydb;trusted_connection=yes" conn.Open sConn
```

Then you're missing instructions separators, or better, separate lines:

```
Dim sConn As String
sConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Server=mydb;trusted_connection=yes"
conn.Open sConn
```

---

Also, on this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

These parentheses are force-passing `objMyRecordset` by value (i.e. a copy of the object pointer) to the `CopyFromRecordset` method. This would be a more typical call:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset
```

If `CopyFromRecordset` is taking the recordset `ByVal`, then it's passed by value. If it's taking it `ByRef`, then it's passed by reference. Forcing `ByVal` is *normally* not needed.

Comment: Also, `objMyRecordset` should be `rec1` ;)